# base width of div on it's relative height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-box container div of a specific height. Inside there are several divs of varying relative widths, and all have height 100% of the container. Each of those divs have a small centered text that I want to display inside a circle. The circle must have a radius that is a percentage of the parent div height.

I know there are several questions out there where people want to base the height of the div on it's relative width, and that there is a trick to solve that by using `padding-top` as an aspect-ratio. But I want the reverse of that. I am starting to think it may not be possible, so I am just asking to make sure.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>relative height exp</title>
        <style>
          #container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
          }
    
          .items {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;       
          }
    
          #item1 {
            width: 10%;
          }
    
          #item2 {
            width: 20%;
          }
    
          #item3 {
            width: 30%;
          }
    
          #item4 {
            width: 40%;
          }
    
          .inner {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 2px solid brown;
            background-color: burlywood;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <div class="items" id="item1">
            <div class="inner">A</div>
          </div>
          <div class="items" id="item2">
            <div class="inner">B</div>
          </div>
          <div class="items" id="item3">
            <div class="inner">C</div>
          </div>
          <div class="items" id="item4">
            <div class="inner">D</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

So, in the css class `inner` I set width to 50% (which obviously doesn't work), but I want to somehow relate it to the height of that class.

Comment: check variable width & variable height

Comment: If you know the height already why not set width the same as height directly.

Comment: this will be a reusable component (I am using React), where the container will be defined by the user. I could use javascript to solve it, but I just want to know if there is a pure css solution.